# Change CSS via @Input in Angular 2/4

Tags: html, angular

I am attempting to streamline my application by using a single template to reference a custom element, and then specify the contents via the @Input() property decorator. The method I am using isn't working and I'm not sure why, my code is as follows:

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'side-menu-option',
  templateUrl: './side-menu-option.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-menu-option.component.css']
})
export class SideMenuOptionComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() icon: string; // Inputs
  @Input() text: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Component.html

```
<button class="buttons button-style btn-block" type="button"><i class="mdi mdi-{{icon}}"></i><span class="menu-text">{{text}}</span></button>
```

OtherComponent.html

```
<div class="side-nav text-center">
  <div class="side-nav-container">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <side-menu-option [icon]="home" [text]="Home"></side-menu-option>
    <side-menu-option [icon]="file-document" [text]="Documents"></side-menu-option>
  </div>
</div>
```

[icon] and [text] are not being recognized for some reason and I am not sure why. It worked before I tried to refactor it, but for some reason these inputs are not being loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to understand that `[icon]="statement here"` takes a statement but you are passing it a string so you have to wrap your string in quotes again to make it a string explicitly.

```
<div class="side-nav text-center">
  <div class="side-nav-container">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <side-menu-option [icon]="'home'" [text]="'Home'"></side-menu-option>
    <side-menu-option [icon]="'file-document'" [text]="'Documents'"></side-menu-option>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** This is also a good practice because one can look at it and will know that these are input properties but if you remove these
>   brackets[] they can be easily confused for attributes. Just want to
>   mention, there is no harm in either approach.

Answer (score 0):

Bind without brackets if your inputs aren't any parent attributes

```
<div class="side-nav text-center">
  <div class="side-nav-container">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <side-menu-option icon="home" text="Home"></side-menu-option>
    <side-menu-option icon="file-document" text="Documents"></side-menu-option>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="side-nav text-center">
  <div class="side-nav-container">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <side-menu-option icon="home" text="Home"></side-menu-option>
    <side-menu-option icon="file-document" text="Documents"></side-menu-option>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove the property binding syntax ([]brackets) for the Input properties in parent component ([item] => item)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I first misunderstood the question, the problem actually is that you should use `'value'` for your values, because Angular will look for variables called `home`, `file-document`, and so on. You should use this instead:

```
<side-menu-option [icon]="'home'" [text]="'Home'"></side-menu-option>
<side-menu-option [icon]="'file-document'" [text]="'Documents'"></side-menu-option>
```

Comment: Is this a better method as opposed to simply removing the brackets?

Comment: @JarredParr I think Raheel Anwar did answer your question in his answer.